# Small change in colors during JPEG compression

Tags: python, opencv, colors, python-imaging-library, jpeg

It looks like default library under Ubuntu changes colors a bit during the compression. I tried to set quality and sampling but I see no improvements, anyone ever challenged similar issue?

subsampling = 0 ,  quality = 100

```
#CORRECT COLORS FROM NPARRAY
cv2.imshow("Object cam:{}".format(self.camera_id), self.out)

print(self.out.item(1,1,0)) # B 
print(self.out.item(1,1,1)) # G
print(self.out.item(1,1,2)) # R

self.out=cv2.cvtColor(self.out,  cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

#from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray(self.out)
r, g, b = im.getpixel((1, 1))
## just printing pixel and they are matching  
print(r, g, b) 
## WRONG COLORS
im.save(self.out_ramdisk_img,format='JPEG', subsampling=0, quality=100)
```

[image]

JPEG image should have the same colors as in imshow, but it's a bit more purple.

Comment: JPEG is a lossy compression. Thus it could change colors somewhat. But I suspect that one image has a color profile and the other does not. Or the color profiles are different on the two versions. Check that.

Answer (score 1):

That is a natural result of JPEG compression. JPEG uses floating point arithmetic to calculate integer pixel values. This occurs in several stages of JPEG compression. Thus, small pixel value changes are expected.

When you have blanket changes in color they are usually the result input color values that are outside the gamut of the YCbCr color space. Such values get clamped.